# How become shadow catcher more strong

Tags: shadowcatcher

I´m using hdr lighting and a real picture with shadows (with shadow catcher method). The problems is the shadows produced from HDR is clear more then background picture. I´d like to obtein the same shadow or like, in the picture.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Passes/Layers:

Pass 1: Background
Pass 2: Shadow Catcher + Holdout Shader for Object
Pass 3: Object with transparent Background and no Shadow Catcher

Then in your prefered compositing solution you can ramp Pass 2 for a darker shadow and combine then all.